# Quartz.Net SQLlite No table QRTZ_LOCKS

Tags: c#, sqlite, quartz.net

I am trying to create a .net 5 Worker Service that contains a Quartz.Net scheduling service. I have Quartz up and running. I am trying to add SQL lite to the mix for a persistent store. However, I keep getting the below exception. What am I missing?

Exception:

```
SQLiteException: SQL logic error
no such table: QRTZ_LOCKS
```

Config Code:

```
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    // Use a Scoped container to create jobs. I'll touch on this later
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

    q.UsePersistentStore(c =>
    {
        c.UseSQLite(@"URI=file:MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        
        c.UseJsonSerializer();
        //c.UseBinarySerializer(); This option didn't make a difference 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the tables before Quartz.Net try's to access them. Here is a sample set up file.

https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzNetAdoJobStoreSQLite/blob/master/QuartzNetAdoJobStoreSQLite/tables_sqlite.sql